# JavaScript: an if statement is changing outcomes of a random generator?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, random

Basically I'm creating a program similar to a blackjack program where two cards are dealt according to a random number generator, with the possibility of the same card being dealt twice at the same time (i.e. two Queen of hearts showing up at once) and I want to create a counter of how many times that event occurs, but when I implement an if statement, it affects the outcome so that the two cards are ALWAYS the exact same...can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? The code is as follows:

```
function dealHand() {
var randomCardOne = Math.floor ((Math.random() *13) +2);
var randomCardTwo = Math.floor ((Math.random() *13) +2);
    if (randomCardOne = randomCardTwo) {identicalCards()};
} 

var identicalPairs = 0;
function identicalCards(){
    document.getElementById("identical").value=++identicalPairs;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the value of one card to another

```
if (randomCardOne = randomCardTwo) {identicalCards()};
```

should be

```
if (randomCardOne == randomCardTwo) {identicalCards()};
```

In the first case you are simply evaluating if randomCardOne is "truthy" after being asigned the value of randomCardTwo.

Consider if you might want to use `===` instead of `==` since

```
2 == '2' // yields true

2 === '2' // yields false
```

It's not an issue in this case but it might be in others so it's good to be aware of this. I try to stick with `===` since it is more strict.

Answer (score 1):

You're using =, that's an assignment operator in JavaScript. You should be using ==

e.g.

```
if (randomCardOne == randomCardTwo) {identicalCards()};
```

Comment: Right, I didn't even think about that! Thank you so much!!

Comment: As mentioned on the other answer: `===` is even better than `==` as it performs an additional type check. Types are clear in this case, but despite `===` being marginally faster, it most of all teaches you a clean coding style.